# How do I use application written in Corda in writing my Spring Boot middleware?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, blockchain, corda

---

Recently I started with Corda blockchain and Spring Boot and I have some doubts.

---

I have created a simple cordapp to create and retrieve the details on Corda. I have written the flow and everything. This application is working fine and I am getting the desired output on terminal.

---

**Now I want to write a SpringBoot application for middleware which can interact with this Cordapp. But how do I use my Cordapp in SpringBoot project as lot of things would be inaccessible like Transactions, flows etc. and will show the error while writing the spring Application.**

---

I am sorry if it sounds to dumb, But I am a fresher and trying to learn some things.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this github repository](https://github.com/joeldudleyr3/spring-observable-stream) that has done exactly what you have asked. It has both the cordapp and the spring webserver as separate projects. If you take a look at the build.gradle file in the server folder, you can see that it includes the cordapp dependencies, and also includes the project dependencies in the form of `cordapp project(:yo)`.

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile "junit:junit:$junit_version"

    // Corda integration dependencies
    cordaCompile "net.corda:corda-core:$corda_release_version"
    cordaCompile "net.corda:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"
    cordaCompile "net.corda:corda-jackson:$corda_release_version"
    cordaCompile "net.corda:corda-rpc:$corda_release_version"
    cordaRuntime "net.corda:corda:$corda_release_version"
    testCompile "net.corda:corda-node-driver:$corda_release_version"

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket:$spring_boot_version") {
    exclude group: "org.springframework.boot", module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
    }
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:$spring_boot_version"
    compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-web:2.7"

    cordapp project(":yo")
}
```

Comment: There is also a more bare-bones example of Corda/Spring integration here: https://github.com/corda/spring-webserver.

Answer (score 0):

[Corbeans](https://manosbatsis.github.io/corbeans/) provides Corda Integration for Spring Boot, for example it auto-configures service beans for your Corda network/nodes. You can use them to communicate with your nodes and call flows etc. using the [RPC interface](https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-clientrpc-api.html) under the hood (or directly).